# React Native: getting "Network Request Failure" on 7th fetch call only

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

In my React Native app, I'm hitting a remote API using this code:

```
const ret = await fetch(ENDPOINT_URL + path, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers,
});
```

I hit it multiple times with different values of `path` when the app loads. I always get "`Network request failure`" after the 7th time I hit it, so I assumed it was a problem with the particular endpoint I hit on the 7th one. However, I tried making it so that it hits that particular endpoint on every iteration, and it still fails only after the 7th one. Also, all requests work fine when I try them from Postman.

Does anyone know how I could approach resolving this? I can't provide the API URL unfortunately, but please let me know if there's any other info that would be useful.

Comment: Hello, are you making fetch requests to an HTTPS connection or is it simply HTTP?

Comment: @AjinKabeer HTTPS, and I should add that every request is working fine when I try it from Postman (API request software)

Comment: I faced a similar problem a while ago. React-Native does not permit requests to HTTP. Yes, requests from Postman will work fine with all connections. If you're running the server locally, you can use something like ngrok. Also, I suggest you to try fetching data from JSON placeholder just to troubleshoot if the error persists.